# Ubuntu server running out of memory when loading python app

Tags: python, ubuntu, memory-management

I'm running a python Flask app on a Ubuntu 14.04 server where I load some data, the two major things being:

- Google News vectors, to be used with Word2vec (the GoogleNewsVec is about 4GB)
- 350MB json file with data

This all loads on my local Windows machine in ~5mins, which has similar specs to the server (8GB RAM). The weird thing is that the two parts seperately load fine. So when I do:

```
load_word2vec_model()
load_json_data()
```

It would load the model really quickly and get stuck at load_json_data():

```
[13:16:55] Loading model..
[13:17:13] Finished loading model.
[13:17:13] Loading scores..
[13:17:13] Loading scores dict from json file..
```

But when i do it in reverse order:

```
load_json_data()
load_word2vec_model()
```

It gets stuck at loading the word2vec model:

```
[13:20:29] Loading scores..
[13:20:29] Loading scores dict from json file..
[13:22:42] Finished loading from json file.
[13:22:42] Finished loading scores.
[13:22:42] Loading model..
```

I do not get any python error message. This leads me to believe that the server somehow reached its max. memory usage, and will not load the entire model.

On my local Windows machine it does use up a lot of memory, but eventually it will load (in about 5 minutes total). Why does this not happen on the server, I've waited for an hour but it never loads.

This is the htop output for the server:

[image]

Comment: This question lacks any traceback or Python error message.

Comment: I don't get any error message. It's like its still loading, but it takes forever..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between your Windows machine and Ubuntu server is most likely caused by pagefile (Windows)/swappiness (Linux) configuration. To sum up, swapping is storing some parts of memory, preferably not-so-important stuff, to disk to make some room for some other process that asks for memory.

Now, end-user targeted Windows machines comes with a pagefile, i.e. the file that is used to write memory contents, size configuration of around 75% of the memory size. But Ubuntu servers, AWS comes to mind, usually comes with no swap partition/file and swappiness, i.e. the likelyhood that your memory will be swapped to disk, set to 0, i.e. not at all.

The solution is either setting up a swap file and swappiness configuration, or throwing more memory at the problem. The former solution will make your application work just as it is on Windows. The latter will solve it for good.

**NVM:**
It seems you have swap enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is really insightful. The problem is that its not my server and I can't throw more memory at it so easily unfortunately.

Comment: You can increase the swap size, but that won't do much good either, if you are on a spinning disk, maybe with SSD it might help. Another possible solution is to sample the data, if applicable. Is GoogleNewsVec trained model or just raw data? Lastly, there is something called [`zram`](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html) I've used it on an old laptop for personal use, didn't get much out of it, but might work out for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I installed the zram-config package and got it to work!